Why is the Tetragrammaton transliterated as "Yahweh"?
Where do scholars get the name “Yahweh” from?  I’ve looked at the Tetragrammaton throughout the Bible.  All uses of the Tetragrammaton seem to be pointed as “y’hovah” (third person of “I am”) except for in Exodus chapter 3 where they are pointed twice as “E’heyeh” (first person of “I am”)  The only pointing of the Tetragrammaton I can find that is pointed similar to “Yahweh” is in Genesis 15:2 which as far as I can tell would be pronounced as “Yahvih”.  I don’t understand why it is pointed different here.  I also don’t understand why scholars use a “w” sound in “Yahweh.”  I heard Hebrew has never had a “w” sound and that the “w” sound didn’t come until later in Aramaic or Arabic after Hebrew.    Can anyone explain?

Yahweh is a transliteration not a translation.

Actually, the story is a bit messy!
Before about 800 AD, the Hebrew text was written without vowel pointings.  However, somewhere about 800 AD the Masoretes decided to preserve the pronunciation of the words and developed the vowel-pointing system we now use.
Now, this is where things get a little messy - the true pronunciation of the tetragrammaton, YHWH had been lost more than 1000 years earlier and thus, the Masoretes did not know what vowels to include.  However, all good scribes would never pronounce the name anyway - they would always say "Adonai" instead.
Therefore, to remind the reader of this tradition, YHWH was pointed with the vowels for "Adonai" which results in a word that would end up in English as "Yehovah".
However, it is not difficult to see that the original word, YHWH is part of the verb "to be" and modern linguists have speculated that its most probable original pronunciation was possibly close to "Yahweh".
Lastly, the debate about "w" vs "v" is a debate between two modern forms of Hebrew, viz German vs Askenazi.  Now, just what the "original" Hebrew used is much debated and thus depends on who you ask.  For what it is worth, I think it was probably closer to "w" but probably depended on the word and context as well as the accent and origin of the speaker.
============
Here's an extra piece to explain the modern reconstruction of the divine name. Although the tetragrammaton stopped being pronounced at some point in antiquity, certain portions of the name continue to be pronounced in the Masoretic reading tradition. There are several passages where the first syllable alone is read Yah (e.g. Exodus 17:16; Psalm 68:4). In addition to this, many names in the Old Testament are theophoric, with part of the divine name either at the beginning or the end. Thus, names like Isaiah (יְשַׁעְיָהוּ Yesha'yahu) or Zephaniah (תְפַנְיָה Zephanyah) ending with "Yahu" or "Yah" confirm the first syllable of Yahweh. The vowel of the second syllable is hypothetical, but it is based on the pronounciation of other masculine singular nouns ending in ה, which consistently end -eh. Putting it all together we get Yahweh/Yahveh.

The verb to be shows future tense according to modern Hebrew. Does this change the meaning of the name from "I am" to "I will be"? There are modern scribes that teach the name according to Genesis 3:12 -  “I will be with you" the actual given name Moses received from God as the identifier.

"ehyeh asher ehyeh" is often translated as "I will be what I will be" or "I will be that I will be".

"but probably depended on the word and context" — that happens in many languages. For instance, in English "S" is often vocalized when between two vowels ("-⁠istic" and "-⁠ism"), and in Polish "W" is pronounced like an English "V" when followed by a vowel and  like "F" when not.

There is no present tense of the verb "to be." I am Joseph is simply I Joseph (for example). Therefore the verb is either was or will be. Which is not to deny the actual presence of one, it points to using the verb when one is actually present is to convey one or in the case of Exodus 3, both of the meanings. I am speaking and I was/will be who I was/will be.

@RevelationLad: There's an infinitive form no?

The bit about "preserve the pronunciation" isn't entirely accurate.  Ancient Hebrew, like other Semitic languages, doesn't require vowel marks when writing: the vowels can be deduced entirely from the consonant pattern.

@Mark Largely, but not always unambiguously, especially with irregular and defective verbs. It's analogous to supposing that no one spoke French anymore and there was no attestation of the verb dire conjugated for vous. A linguist could easily derive vous disez, but would be less likely to figure out the actual form vous dites. That would involve detailed knowledge of older and related languages and careful phonological and morphological reconstruction. That's the case with yahweh, which is, incidentally, one of the most defective verbs possible (three weak consonants, היה).

But even with regular forms, there are cases where one has to rely on pragmatic, not just semantic or syntactic context. A surprising example is that some instances of הוא in Genesis are pointed with a hiriq, which is not expected on the waw, because it's evident that the story must be talking about a female character (and/or because the oral keepers of the text remembered saying /i/ there, not /u/). Another kind is that there are verbs that could be ambiguously jussive or imperfective, depending on the vowels, and either one would make sense in context.

Has the final ה ever been pronounced in words in Biblical Hebrew? Hasn't it always mean't "there is a final open syllable here" as it does in Modern Hebrew? Of course, sometimes it is part of the root and that is another reason to show it.

"always" was wrong of course. The h is pronounced if the he has a mapiq הּ.
